# Convert MongoDb query in spring data mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document with an array. I want to delete the document if array exists and size is of 0.

I came up with this mongodb query(something similar)

```
document.remove({ comments: { $exists: true, $size: 0 } })
```

please help me in converting this mongodb query to spring-data-mongodb or suggest me if there is any better solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `Document` class.

```
mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(Criteria.where("comments").exists(true).size(0)), Document.class);
```